# How to get intermediate results from long running operation?

Tags: c#, events, dependency-injection, system.reactive

Take the following class and suppose `Calculate` is a very calculation intensive function.

```
class Algorithm
{
    FinalResultObject Calculate()
    {
        longPartialCalculation();
        //signal to caller that that part is ready of type MidResult1
        morePartialCalculation();
        //signal more is ready, different type of  MidResult2
        moreWork();
        return finalResult;             
    }
}
```

Now suppose, intermediate results need to be shown to the user whenever they're ready.

The options I see are:

1. use separate events to signal
2. use constructor injection to inject the a handler class whose methods are being called
3. use RX observables

I'm new to RX but I'm liking the idea that I can easily do the event handling on the UI thread. I'm wondering though if this is overkill and not as intended since it's not really a whole stream of data but just one result for each observable. On the other hand though just as with events subscription and unsubscription seems to be so cumbersome.

Any hints?

Comment: Unless this worker is going to outlive whatever it is reporting progress to by a significant margin (which should almost never be the case) there'd be no need to unsubscribe from events; the object holding the events should be dying before any of the objects adding handlers to it.

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand this question, but instead of providing special progress reporting event you can also poll operation in progress, then you do not need event, subscribing and unsubscribing.

Comment: My understanding of the question is not how to get progress out of some closed operation, but how to report progress that the computation makes available. It's simply a question of how to expose progress notifications.

Comment: @Servy so you're suggesting the way to go would be via events? The UI is definately going to outlive the `Algorithm` class. But since the `Calculate()` is not going to run on the UI thread I'd need to channel the event handlers back to the dispatcher.

Comment: @All of you: I've actually had trouble googling this question. It seems I can't really find a real world sample of my problem which I'm wondering about since it feels common. I need the `Algorithm` class encapsulated since it needs to be interchangeable. The inbetween steps don't have a particular order that's why I can't expose several methods like `CalculationStep1()` and so on.

Comment: @Sinatr: I would rather not do polling. The timing restrictions are *tiiiight*. It sounds strange but I'm really counting on every millisecond (there's a PLC and a physical machine behind this. Calculation needs to finish within 500ms and I'm barely making that. Now count in some delay for ethernet and I'd need to poll every millisecond, which I have the feeling will take away from the rest of the calculation)

Comment: @Dave, you got that right. Just wanted to say thanks and +1 for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rx way of tackling this problem is to define a **cold** observable as follows:

```
IObservable<Result> Calculate(IScheduler scheduler)
{
  return Observable.Create<Result>(observer => 
    scheduler.Schedule(() =>
    {
       observer.OnNext(longPartialCalculation());
       observer.OnNext(morePartialCalculation());
       observer.OnNext(moreWork());
       observer.OnCompleted();
    }));
}

// Depending upon your needs, you could use inheritance as follows:
public abstract class Result { ... }
public class MidResult1 : Result { ... }
public class MidResult2 : Result { ... }
public class FinalResultObject : Result { ... }
```

You could also define an overload that specifies a default scheduler, such as `ThreadPoolScheduler` if you want to introduce concurrency or `CurrentThreadScheduler` if you don't.

To use the observable that is returned by this method, simply call `Subscribe` with an observer. You can provide an `OnNext` handler to inspect each `Result` object as it arrives and an `OnCompleted` handler to handle completion. You can also provide an `OnError` handler to handle an `Exception`, if you must.
*(Edit: Note that `OnError` isn't called by my example though.)*

If you want to ensure that all of these handlers execute on the UI thread, and you've passed in a concurrency-introducing scheduler such as `ThreadPoolScheduler` to the `Calculate` method, then you can also apply the `ObserveOn` operator (or `ObserveOnDispatcher` on XAML-based platforms) to marshal all notifications to the UI thread for observation.

```
algo.Calculate(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(OnNextResult, OnCompleted);
```

Note that one of the primary benefits of Rx is the ability to query; e.g., a simple filter:

```
algo.Calculate(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .Where(result => result.HasRequiredState)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(result => handle(result.RequiredState));
```

Comment: I thought about the idea of having just one observable. I was having trouble justifying the abstract `Result` class (or even an interface) because all that it could potentially share would be a `public object Value{get;}` which would mean type checking and casting within `OnNextResult()`. On the other hand it could be empty leaving explicitly typed properties on the inheriting classes. Then the `Result` classes only purpose was to combine all the results in the one Observable. That's why I was thinking of exposing several Observables (one for each result) on the `Algorithm` class.

Comment: The problem with having more than one observable is synchronization. Observables represent concurrency in Rx, so having more than one implies that 2 observers, for instance, may receive notifications simultaneously. Of course, you're marshaling to the UI thread anyway, although there still may be a race between the observables to the dispatcher, depending how you would code it. Regardless, it's just more natural in Rx to model a sequence of notifications in a single observable -- that's what it's for!

Comment: The `Result` class is just a way to carry additional information. Perhaps you don't need it at all. Just use an `IObservable<T>` where `T` is the current computed value; e.g., `IObservable<int>` could represent the completion percentages, such that 0 is pushed immediately, 50 is pushed half-way and 100 is pushed immediately before `OnCompleted` is called.

Comment: The inheritance idea was just a suggestion. You have other choices if you need pairs of data; e.g., you could encode the kind in an enum and provide it as a property on the `Result` class, or you could just use a `Tuple<Phase, Value>` instead. The `Result` class is just a way of being more explicit than `Tuple`, because it's always much nicer to work with semantic properties rather than `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.

Comment: You may find a blog post of mine helpful: http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Rx-The-Power-of-T.aspx

Comment: Ultimately, as you've noted, it seems that you want `IObservable<object>`, which represents a sequence of *any* possible computed values. I'm assuming that you're modeling a general-purpose algorithm, so if the consumer is able to define the shape of derived types of `Result`, then surely it could directly define the `T` in `IObservable<T>`. Thus, perhaps you'll want to literally return `IObservable<T>` from `Calculate`, without any constraints on `T`. Simply cast each result to `T` before passing it to `OnNext`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .Net's `Progress<T>`. You create an instance, passing a handler or registering to its event and report through it throughout you long-running process:

```
var progress = new Progress<string>(value => Console.WriteLine(value));
Calculate(progress);

FinalResultObject Calculate(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    longPartialCalculation();
    progress.Report("MidResult1");
    morePartialCalculation();
    progress.Report("MidResult2");
    moreWork();
    return finalResult;
}
```

In this case, the report is writing a string to console, but you can of course use for any type you want.

`Progress<T>` also captures the current `SynchronizationContext` on creation so you could create it in the UI thread, pass it to a non-UI thread without any synchronization issues.

Comment: Interesting! That's a class I've not encountered before! It looks very similar to RX's Observables though and the same questions arise: Since the intermediate results are of different types I would need either type checking and casting or `Progress<T>`'s . Thanks for the alternative though!

Comment: @MarkusHütter It depends on what you're planning to notify. The simplest option is percentage, so `Progress<int>`. What I would have done is probably create a `CalculateProgress` enum with all the stages and report when each stage completes.

Comment: ... and then pull each stages' result in a switch on the enum?

Comment: @MarkusHütter you can. again, it depends on what you're using the results for. You can even have `Progress<Action>` where you post actual delegates to execute.